# Golang Webserver can't be accessed from Docker

Tags: curl, docker, go, gorilla

I am using the Gorilla framework in Go to expose a webservice. I have a "Hello World" endpoint at `/hello` which works fine when hit from Postman, browser or `curl`.

The problem arises when I bundle it with Docker. My Dockerfile is as below

```
FROM alpine
COPY ./target/himer-users-go /app
ENV PORT 9000
RUN echo $PORT
ENTRYPOINT /app
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

Now I can `ssh` into the container and ping the server using `wget` (since `alpine` doesn't come bundled with `curl`)

But when I run the image like

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 namespace/image
```

I can't access the server in any way from my host system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: alpine does not come with a SSH server installed and configured, you should use `docker exec` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by exposing the server at `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`

The problem is that I've told my webserver to only serve requests sent to localhost. Because of the network mangling that Docker does, none of the traffic showing up to your webserver look to the webserver as though they were sent to `localhost`. By telling the webserver to listen on `0.0.0.0`, I'm effectively telling it that it doesn't care where the traffic was originally sent and it will accept it all.

Comment: I have lost 2 hours to solve it, before your post, thank you